# How to split pairing text on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataframe

```
Place               Pair
Boat Semeru          Andy.Johnson Mary.Smith, Adam.Roger Bella.Huri
Boat Merbabu         Sena.Batra Lera.Clara, Tracy.Roger Bella.Salsa, Iman.Veva Umi.Zuba
```

Here's my expected output

```
Place                Husband          Wife
Boat Semeru          Andy.Johnson     Mary.Smith
Boat Semeru          Adam.Roger       Bella.Huri
Boat Merbabu         Sena.Batra       Lera.Clara
Boat Merbabu         Tracy.Roger      Bella.Salsa
Boat Merbabu         Iman.Veva        Umi.Zuba
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` with `explode`

```
df['Pair'] = df['Pair'].str.split(', ')
df = df.explode('Pair',ignore_index=True)
df[['Husband','Wife']] = df.pop('Pair').str.split(' ').tolist()
df
Out[412]: 
          Place       Husband         Wife
0   Boat Semeru  Andy.Johnson   Mary.Smith
1   Boat Semeru    Adam.Roger   Bella.Huri
2  Boat Merbabu     ena.Batra   Lera.Clara
3  Boat Merbabu   Tracy.Roger  Bella.Salsa
4  Boat Merbabu     Iman.Veva     Umi.Zuba
```

Comment: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: I know why, will try to solve this in next question